Array with adjustable bracket size
Probably relevant
I want to typeset 6j symbols. Ordinary ones are easy with the array command and doing the curly brackets with left and right command. Even I could do it. But I have 6j symbols with multiplicity labels. Lazy standard is writing them as index to the right. OK, but writing them over and under the spins IMHO looks better, and, which is more important, you can see faster which spin triple the label belongs to. I now could easily put the brackets around the whole stack, but that now more looks like a 12j symbol with forgotten spins. On the other hand, if the bracket is of the same size an ordinary 6j symbol would have, I guess it is a bit too small. I have to simply experiment which size of the bracket looks best. Copied example with labels "abcd" and a 6j symbol "123456" inserted, where the bracket is too large:
\[ \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
  & a &   \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
b & c & d \end{array} \right\} \] 

Can you give me a quick fix where I can adjust the bracket size? I only need to do that once. (Possibly the link above already gives the answer, but I'm a TeX n00b.)

your question is very unclear, assume most readers do not know what part of the tex you are referring to when you reference by subject terms such as spin or 6j. You should just say what change you want to make to the output. I can not guess what change you want but perhaps change \left\{ \right} to \biggl\{\biggr\} or \Bigl or \Biggl or whatever size you need

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but it sounds like you are asking two questions. First, how can we get all brackets the same size even if the content is larger inside some of them? Second, how can we overset and underset information to content in an array?

For the first question, you can use the manual sizing commands \bigl, \Bigl, \biggl and \Biggl with their respective right-side commands (\bigr, etc.). You might want to make a \newenvironment as in the code below.
For the second question, the \overset and \underset commands from the amsmath package might be more to your liking compared to adding additional rows to your matrix. The macros \multover and \multunder in the code make this a bit simpler.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{sixj}{\biggl\{\begin{array}{ccc}}{\end{array}\biggr\}}
\newcommand{\multover}[2]{\overset{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\multunder}[2]{\underset{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{sixj}
1 & \multover{a}{2} & 3 \\
\multunder{b}{4} & \multunder{c}{5} & \multunder{d}{6} 
\end{sixj} 
%
\begin{sixj}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 
\end{sixj}
\]

\end{document}


Looks already quite good, optically. Maybe the over/under in larger font.
